# Как сравнить 3 числа?

Tags: linux, c, числа

Имеется 3 числа:

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;
unsigned int c;
```

Их значения задаются по ходу выполнения программы. А потом надо эти значения сравнить, чтобы найти наименьшее, а именно:

```
// сравниваем числа
if (smallest == a) {
    ...
} else if (smallest == b) {
    ...
} else if (smallest == c) {
    ...
}
```

Самое первое, что приходит в голову - связка if/else. Но даже с тремя числами такая связка будет весьма длинная, что не очень удобно. И что хуже - два из трёх чисел могут быть и равными, что неудобно, особенно если это будут два наименьших числа. Не подскажете, как коротко и грамотно оформить такое сравнение? Ещё лучше, если это обернуть в функцию вида

```
int num_match() {
   int smallest;
   ...
   return smallest;
}
```

Comment: Так а что делать, если два одинаковых наименьших числа? Вы так и не написали... Вам нужна просто функция, возвращающая наименьшее число? `min(a,min(b,c))` :) Но, похоже, вам надо что-то другое. Дайте точное ТЗ, иначе ответ получается ХЗ...

Comment: эм, что то тут не хватает. но может вот это `int num_match(int a, int b, int c) { int smallest = a; smallest = smallest > b?:b:smallest; smallest = smallest > c?:c:smallest; return smallest;`

Comment: @KoVadim Да как-то не вяжется это с названием `num_match()`...

Comment: ну вот и я тоже написал об этом. пойду тряпочку поищу, шар протереть

Comment: ТЗ я ясное дал. Надо выяснить наименьшее число из трёх чисел. Я сказал, что МОЖНО обернуть это в функцию, но НЕ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО.

Comment: Насчет ясного ТЗ Вы заблуждаетесь. Где в вопросе хоть слово о нахождении наименьшего??? Там сказано - "надо сравнить". Как сравнивать - ни слова в вопросе нет.

Comment: спасибо, поправил

Comment: Тогда выбирайте из первых двух комментариев. Вариант Harry проще, вариант KoVadim не использует библиотечных функций.

Comment: Harry, спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ок, допустим, что нужно искать минимальное с трех. Что бы не мешалось, лучше завернуть в функцию (или макрос, по обстоятельствам).

Я предлагаю объявить функцию вот так

```
int min3i(int a, int b, int c) {
  int smallest = a;
  smallest = smallest > b?:b:smallest;
  smallest = smallest > c?:c:smallest;
  return smallest;
}
```

хотя лучше уже написать так

```
int min3i(int a, int b, int c) {
  int smallest = a;
  if (b < smallest) { smallest = b;}
  if (c < smallest) { smallest = c;}
  return smallest;
}
```

и теперь можно использовать как `int m = min3i(1,2,5);`. Почему я добавил `3i` в название? это си, тут нельзя иметь функции с разным кол-вом параметров и одним именем.

Если же хочется макросов (ну потому что сравниваются не только int, а и float и другое, то вот такой способ (улучшим идею от @Harry)

```
#define min(a,b) ((a)>(b))?(b):(a)
#define min3(a,b,c) min((a), min((b), (c)))
```

Скобки нужны, так как иначе могут быть чудеса, к примеру, с таким выражением `min3(a+b, b+c, 3)` (надеюсь, я их достаточно поставил).

Comment: Во втором макросе в конце не хватает  одной закрывающей скобки...

Comment: как знал:) макросы

Comment: надо на LISP тренироваться, чтобы не ошибаться со скобочками :)

Comment: лиспом я давно занимался. Пока к нему возвращаться не хочу.

Comment: Только макрос `min(a, b)` надо бы переписать в виде выражения c локальными  `__typeof__` в фигурных скобoчках

Comment: Возможно. Но для char* это не сильно поможет

Comment: Не понимаю конструкцию `b?:b:smallest`. Какой-то задвоенный тернарный оператор или GNU расширение. Скобочек бы туда))